# pyplot rectangle animation leaves initial rectangle displayed

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, rectangles

I'm new to matplotlib, and I am trying to understand how animation works.

I wrote the following Python code to move around a rectangle:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class AnimRect(object):
    '''Animate a rectangle'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
        # create the axes
        self.ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100), aspect='equal')
        # create rectangle
        self.rect = plt.Rectangle((70,20), 10, 10, 
                                  fill=True, color='gold', ec='blue')
        self.ax.add_patch(self.rect)

    # initialization function
    def init(self):
        self.rect.set_xy((10.0, 10.0))
        return self.rect, 

    # animation function
    def animate(self, i):
        self.rect.set_xy((i,i))
        return self.rect, 

    def call_animation(self):
        # call the animator function
        animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, frames=91, 
                                init_func= self.init,
                                interval=20, blit=True, repeat=False)

        plt.show()

def main():
    rect = AnimRect()
    rect.call_animation()

main()
```

When I run the code, the rectangle that was set at the initial position (10.0,10.0) always stays on screen, while the animated rectangle behaves as expected. I cannot figure why. I tried several minor changes, but could not find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the visibility of the patch to False in the init method, or do away with it entirely.

**With init method - it is useful in some cases:**
Please note that I set `blit=false` because it has some strange behavior with mac os backend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class AnimRect(object):
    '''Animate a rectangle'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
        # create the axes
        self.ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100), aspect='equal')
        # create rectangle
        self.rect = plt.Rectangle((70,20), 10, 10, 
                                  fill=True, color='gold', ec='blue')
        self.ax.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.call_animation()
        plt.show()

    # initialization function
    def init(self):
        self.rect.set_xy((10.0, 10.0))
        self.rect.set_visible(False)
        return self.rect, 

    # animation function
    def animate(self, i):
        self.rect.set_xy((i,i))
        self.rect.set_visible(True)
        return self.rect, 

    def call_animation(self):
        # call the animator function
        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, frames=91,
                                init_func= self.init,
                                interval=20, blit=False, repeat=True)


def main():
    rect = AnimRect()

main()
```

**Without the init:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class AnimRect(object):
    '''Animate a rectangle'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
        # create the axes
        self.ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,100), aspect='equal')
        # create rectangle
        self.rect = plt.Rectangle((70,20), 10, 10, 
                                  fill=True, color='gold', ec='blue')
        self.ax.add_patch(self.rect)
        self.call_animation()
        plt.show()

    # animation function
    def animate(self, i):
        self.rect.set_xy((i,i))
        self.rect.set_visible(True)
        return self.rect, 

    def call_animation(self):
        # call the animator function
        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, frames=91,
                                interval=20, blit=False, repeat=True)

def main():
    rect = AnimRect()

main()
```

Comment: That solved the problem. The solution with the init method works with me (Anaconda Python 3.4 for Windows) with blit either True or False. The second solution does require blit to be set to False.

Comment: Good, glad I could help. I think `blit` must be set to False in the second case because `blit` has to first `delete` the elements that changed; in the absence of the `init` method, there are no element to delete and it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization function `init_func` initializes *each frame*, and not animation as a whole; that is, it is being called in the beginning of each frame. Throw it out and see what happens.

Comment: That was indeed the source of my confusion. I can't remember reading that important remark in the documentation or the tutorials.